# Get all Selected values of Select list via Form Submit - Jquery Chosen

Tags: jquery, jquery-chosen

I am using Jquery Chosen Plugin.

I have this MultiSelect List on my Page.

```
<select name="articles_on_this_menu" multiple="multiple" data-placeholder="Choose Articles" id="articles_on_this_menu">
    <option value="27" selected="selected">Join Team</option>
    <option value="11">Faislabad</option>
    <option value="12">Peshawar</option>
    <option value="28" selected="selected">Track your Order</option>
    <option value="34" selected="selected">AboutUS2</option>
</select>
```

I want to save these SELECTED values by POSTing via FORM submit.

But When submitted, I only get the last selected value from List.

I know I can get all selected values via Jquery by

```
var articles_on_this_menu= $("#articles_on_this_menu").val()
```

But I want to get in FORM submit .... If I do `articles_on_this_menu[]` then I dont get the MultiSelect list in `Chosen Plugin` way

**EDIT:**
People are posting answers in JS or Jquery solutions but I already said please I do not want to use any JS or JQuery. I want to get all selected values in an Array upon Form Submit

Answer (score 2):

Using `articles_on_this_menu[]` in html works fine in PHP.

If you are using python in the backend, use this:(no need to change the html)
`request.POST.getlist('articles_on_this_menu')` for Django and
`request.form.getlist('articles_on_this_menu')` for flask frameworks respectively.

Answer (score 1):

Edited HTML Code:

```
 <select name="articles_on_this_menu[]" multiple="multiple" data-placeholder="Choose Articles" id="articles_on_this_menu">
        <option value="27" selected="selected">Join Team</option>
        <option value="11">Faislabad</option>
        <option value="12">Peshawar</option>
        <option value="28" selected="selected">Track your Order</option>
        <option value="34" selected="selected">AboutUS2</option>
    </select>
```

Use the multi-select name as an array name="articles_on_this_menu[]"
Then you shall get the array of selected options on submitting the form.

PHP Code:

```
//Array of selected articles

$selectArticles = isset($_POST['articles_on_this_menu']) 
    ? $_POST['articles_on_this_menu'] 
    : array();
```

Comment: Why is this not the accepted answer? This answers the question in a completely HTML way, just as requested.

Answer (score 0):

i hope this is what you are looking for , i have jus did the same task but for different reason.

```
 var data = {'cat_ids[]' : []};
        $('select').find('option:selected').each(function(){                    
                data['cat_ids[]'].push($(this).val());                  

        }); 

var posting = $.post("you url here",data);
        posting.done(function( data ){
            $('ID/Class').empty().append(data);

            });
```

in your php file you can get the contents

```
 print_r($_POST['cat_ids']);
```

Comment: u are posting via Jquery ... while I need to post via Form submit only

Comment: than simply change the name of the select tag from articles_on_this_menu to articles_on_this_menu[] and than u will get an array after submitting

Comment: By doing `articles_on_this_menu[]` I get the select list as simple HTML reders ... not like CHOSEN plugin does

Answer (score 0):

**Use below code**  - Use [:selected - selector](http://api.jquery.com/selected-selector/)

```
var selectedValueArray= []; 
$('#articles_on_this_menu :selected').each(function(i, selected){ 
  selectedValueArray[i] = $(selected).text(); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Abhiram Pappula's answer is almost perfect, however, I had to include open and close brackets too to actually get the list result in Flask:

So instead of

```
request.form.getlist('articles_on_this_menu')
```

Use:

```
request.form.getlist('articles_on_this_menu[]')
```